# REGEXP_REPLACE back-reference

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have went through the documentation of Oracle regarding `REGEXP_REPLACE` function, but it didn't work as expected

Here is what I got:

---

**My target:** concatenate a character for each set of continuous numbers

**My input:**

```
(1101 + 1102) * 1103 + 1104 + 1105
```

**Expected output:**

```
(T1101 + T1102) * T1103 + T1104 + T1105
```

**Code:**

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE('(1101 + 1102) * 1103 + 1104 + 1105',
                 '[0-9]+',
                 'T\1') "REZ"
  FROM DUAL;
```

**Result I've got:**

```
(T\1 + T\1) * T\1 + T\1 + T\1
```

---

I've searched many Stack-overflow posts, and they all seems to have this scenario working without any problems regarding the \1

Also tried different places to test the code: Tod for oracle, SqlPlus and another application, they all gave me the same results.

So, would anyone please tell me whats wrong with my code ?

***Note:***

*I don't suspect that my regular expression has any problems, tested before in a different scenario in oracle, and its working.  Plus, matches are found, but the replacement part is not working.*

References of some Stack-overflow posts:

[Ref1](//stackoverflow.com/questions/11238487/regex-replace-not-working-as-expected-in-oracle-10g), [Ref2](//stackoverflow.com/questions/12584261/oracle-sql-regexp-replace-matching), [Ref3](//stackoverflow.com/questions/24763025/oracle-regexp-replace-with-group)

Reference to Oracle Documentation:

[REGEXP_REPLACE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm)

Comment: You don't seem to have a group in your regex. Try to match `([0-9]+)` instead

Comment: This wouldn't add anything new to the accepted answer, so I won't. Thanks for offering the vote, though ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\1` is [back reference](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html) that looks for previous matched groups and groups can be captured by enclosing it inside the parenthesis `(...)`

It should be

```
([0-9]+)
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Follow the link for more detail. You can use `(\d+)` as well